# Android Build Hint android.xactivity Error (using NetBeans)

Tags: android, android-activity, build, codenameone, hint

I tried to add Native Android Activity. I did

```
android.xactivity = <activity android:name="com.appne.exam.NFCActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter></activity>
```

But that gives me Build Errors:

```
    at com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.manifest.ManifestHelperKt.mergeManifestsForApplication(ManifestHelper.kt:83)
    ... 102 more
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 27; columnNumber: 1; Element type "activity" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(ErrorHandlerWrapper.java:203)
```

The build was successful without this particular build hint. I closed all tags well and ensured it's a single line, and no line breaks. Please What am I missing?

```
Error Log line 1-20
User-level: 9000
Request Args: 
-----------------
build.incSources=1
android.xactivity=<activity android:name="com.juliocmms.exam.NFCActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" ><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter></activity>
java.version=8
android.xpermissions=<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC"/>
ios.newStorageLocation=true
-------------------
Effective build tools version = 30
Executing: 
Executing: /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/android create project --target android-33 --name NFCuju --path /tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju --activity NFCujuStub --package com.juliocmms.exam --gradle --gradle-version 4.1.1 /home/ec2-user/android-sdk/tools/android create project --target android-33 --name NFCuju --path /tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju --activity NFCujuStub --package com.juliocmms.exam --gradle --gradle-version 4.1.1 
Executing with timeout -1
Created directory /tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju/src/main/java
Created directory /tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju/src/main/java
Created directory /tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju/src/main/java/com/juliocmms/exam
Created directory /tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju/src/main/java/com/juliocmms/exam
Added file Added file /tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju/src/main/java/com/juliocmms/exam/NFCujuStub.java
/tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju/src/main/java/com/juliocmms/exam/NFCujuStub.java
Created directory Created directory /tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju/src/androidTest/java/tmp/build595835833784802315xxx/NFCuju/src/androidTest/java
........
...... line 107 - 121
      <activity android:name="NFCujuStub"
<activity android:name="com.juliocmms.exam.NFCActivity" android:label="@string/app_name" ><intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" /></intent-filter></activity> android:exported="true"                  android:theme="@style/CustomTheme"
                  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|screenLayout"
                  android:launchMode="singleTop"
                  android:label="NFCuju">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
  <receiver android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.LocalNotificationPublisher"  android:exported="false"></receiver>
<receiver android:name="com.codename1.location.BackgroundLocationBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true"></receiver>
<service android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.BackgroundFetchHandler" android:exported="false" />
<activity android:name="com.codename1.impl.android.CodenameOneBackgroundFetchActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />
<activity android:name="com.codename1.location.CodenameOneBackgroundLocationActivity" android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoDisplay" />

I hope i included the right portions, its 4865 lines in all. I copied and pasted from the first activity tag to the last
```

Comment: Can you include the error log from the server. It includes a lot of additional details including the manifest file and how the build server receives the build hints.

Comment: Thanks Shai for your reply. Please I've edited and tried to add portions of the Error Log hoping I included the relevant portions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see from the generated manifest the `android.xactivity` build hint is there not to add an additional activity but rather to add custom attributes to the default android activity.

What you're looking for is the build hint `android.xapplication`.